# Cannot push files to remote repository

Tags: git, gitlab, git-remote

I cloned an empty `repo` for a project I'm invited to, but then cannot push files to the remote (first time push).

```
git remote -v
origin  https://gitlab.com/project-path (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/project-path (push)
```

I can confirm I successfully added my `ssh` public key:

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
Welcome to GilLab, @username!
```

But unable to push file:

```
git push README.md
fatal: invalid gitfile format: README.md
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you mean *"push files"*? That's not how it works at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't push a file to a remote branch. `git push` operates on branches.

Here's an simple workflow.

```sh
# modify the README.md file, or any other file

# add it and make a commit
git add REAME.md
git commit -m "update README"

# push the branch to remote, replace "<remote-repo>" with real repo name
git push <remote-repo> <branch>
# or
git push <remote-repo> <local-branch>:<remote-branch>
# eg
git push origin master
```

BTW, you ssh public key won't be used in `git push` in this situation. Cause the "remote" branch `origin` is using `https` protocol, but not `git` protocol.

Comment: can you add details to your answer?

Comment: @arilwan You can't push a file to a remote branch. `git push` operates on branches. Please google a `git` tutorial. This is the very basic concept in `git`.

Comment: @arilwan Updated my answer. Detailed enough now.